# Compounding under uncertainty-is Monte Carlo the only way

Tags: statistics

The math behind compounding with a fixed rate of return is a piece of cake.  However what happens if the mechanism of compounding has an uncertain rate of return characterized by a normal distribution-think the stock market where the mean rate of return is .08 with a standard deviation of .18. What is the final result after 20 years of compounding.  This is a practical question related to saving for a child's education, saving for retirement, or outliving a nest egg. Financial advisors typically give an incorrect answer.  I have addressed the problem with a Monte Carlo approach.  See https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/compounding-under-uncertainty-john-hogan/ Is there a closed form solution for this problem. Basically we are taking a normal distribution with mean 1.08 and standard deviation .18 (for the stock market case but we want to obviously generalize) and compounding it 20 times

Comment: Given the multiplicative nature of interest compounding, I think I would take a logarithm to get instead an additive model.  Then the expected log of compounded rate of return would be easily computed from the proposed distribution of annual (or other compounding periods) rates of return.  Alternatively you could avoid Monte Carlo by using a Markov Model approach to generating year-upon-year probabilities for rates of return.

Comment: I have tried that approach and I think it gives me the distribution of a random variable raised to the 20th power as opposed to 20 iterations of a random variable with each iteration being a new random selection of the variable from a given normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider continuous compounding a closed form solution can be built for the distribution of the investment over the long term.  Use the LOGNORMDIST function in excel with mean of ((r-sig^2/2))*T and standard deviation of sig*sqrt(T). r is the yearly mean rate of return, sig is the standard deviation around this mean, and T is the number of years over which the investment is compounded.  Using excel to plot this distribution matches the Monte Carlo method.  I couldn't derive it.  I just know it works.

Answer (score 0):

Put another way.  Consider an annual rate of return with mean r and standard deviation sig.  If this return is continuously compounded with the specified uncertainty for T years than the final value R will be a log normal probability distribution.  The log of R will be normally distributed with a mean of (r-sig^2/2)*T.  The log of R will have a standard deviation of sig*sqrt(T).  I can't prove or derive this but it provides the same result as the brute force Monte Carlo method